# How to listen for observable change inside the component

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Right now I have an interval that checks if my observable changes every 1 second. I know this is not the most efficient way, but I can't figure out how to listen for the state change and run a function when it does, directly in the component. Here is my interval that I have now:

**UPDATE 1:**
I am now using subscribe, but this is still not working for me. I am send a firebase object observable from an already subscribed observable. Is this where my problem lies?

**Service**

```
   private ReadyObs;

   SetRoom(){
   this.Room = this.AngularFire.database.object('/Rooms/ABC1');
    this.Room.subscribe(snap => {
        if(snap.$value !== null){
          this.Ready = this.AngularFire.database.object(`/Rooms/${player.room}/Ready`);
         }
      }

    checkReady(){
      return this.ReadyObs;
    }
```

**Component**

```
   private ReadyObs=this.main.checkReady();

   //Always results with still not ready even though its true
   this.ReadyObs.subscribe((result) =>{
    if(result === true)
      console.log("Ready to use");
     else
       console.log("Still not ready");
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

If **checkReady()** is returning an Observable you can subscribe to it to get changes.

```
this.checkReady()
  .subscribe(result => {
    if (result === true) {
      console.log("Ready");
    } else {
      console.log("Still not ready");
    }
  }, (error) => {

  });
```

Comment: Im trying this, but for some reason this doesn't work for me I will update my code